# "В" или "на" Украину? Интересуют официальные источники

Tags: предлоги, toponyms

На фоне всё большего количества адептов предлога "в" в данном вопросе, становится интересно: а что говорят по этому поводу официальные источники? Есть ли официальные источники, утверждающие, что говорить "в Украину" -- правильно?

Comment: Украинские и приравненные к ним?

Comment: Если украинский источник (американский, российский, марокканский) будет авторитетным -- почему бы и нет? Главное, чтобы он таковым был.

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46568/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%92-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дмитрий, школа грамматистов делится на два больших лагеря - я не про русскую а вообще. Например, французская столетиями зиждилась на том, что есть некая норма, некий правильный язык - и её надо придерживаться. Назовём этот лагерь пуристами. Другой подход - назовём его условном статистическим - отслеживается, какая из форм употребляется всё чаще, какая начинает употребляться реже - и просто констатируется факт - нормой стало вот это вот.

С языками, массово используемыми в нескольких странах ситуация становится ещё запутанней. Есть американский английский и есть английский Великобритании - определённое количество речевых оборотов и правил орфографии в этих странах разнитcя *по факту*. В США говорят **truck**, в Великобритании говорят **lorry**. Если задать на английском форуме вопрос - скажите пожалуйста, всё-таки мне нужен авторитетный источник - правильно truck или lorry - то вопрос этот закроют как риторический и, честно говоря бессмысленный.

Есть факт - украинские русскоязычные люди предпочитают говорить "в Украине", определённое части российской русскоязычной аудитории это режет слух, для какой-то её части этот вопрос вдруг перетекает в политическую плоскость.

Вы просите авторитетных источников, пожалуйста, у Розенталя [читаем](http://2yxa.ru/rus/styli_xlv_199_2.wml):

> Административно-географическими наименованиями употребляется предлог
>   **в**, например: в городе, в районе, в области, в республике; в Сибири, в
>   Белоруссии, в Закавказье. Сочетание **на Украине** возникло под влиянием
>   украинского языка (ср.: на Полтавщине, на Черниговщине) и
>   поддерживается выражением на окраине.

То есть Дитмар Эльяшевич фактически говорит следующее - вообще говорят "в", но под влиянием украинского существует форма "на " - к тому же есть слово окраина и форма образована по аналогии с ней (мы сейчас оставляем за скобками это замечание, оно не имеет отношения к делу).

Достаточно для вас Розенталь авторитетный источник? 
Может быть, вам будет комфортней, если это будет там не знаю, какой-нибудь административный акт?

Это всё не важно, важно что по факту норма употребляется.

Вот например, москвичи часто говорят "сосиська" и "тётька" - мне ужасно режет это слух, но поправлять их - дело неблагодарное.

Comment: Ссылка на мнение Дмитрия Эльяшевича была бы убедительной, если бы источником было прижизненное издание после 90-го года, когда автор уже имел дело с ситуацией существования одноимённого государства. Я помню своё первое впечатление от сочетания "Сделано в Украине", которое значилось на одном измерительном приборе. Наверняка, в те времена оно удивляло и тамошних русскоязычных граждан. Сейчас я не вижу проблем с дифференцированным употреблением предлогов - всему своё место, это было бы удобно и информативно.

Comment: Мы ведь не говорим "на Берегу Слоновой Кости", а предлог "на" употреблеяем только по отношению к островным государствам (Куба, Цейлон). Не вижу и влияния украинского языка в выражении "на Брянщине" (на этой "территории"). Я это не ради дискуссии говорю (она нынче всегда бывает бесплодна), а как комментарий к мнению уважаемого всеми автора - мог ли он в момент его высказывания иметь в виду возникшее государство?